# Expanding the integrand gives a different result

Tags: integration, limits

I integrated this term in *Mathematica*:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega\cdot \sin(s\cdot \omega)\cdot \frac{1}{e^{\beta\cdot \hbar\cdot \omega}-1}\cdot \frac{\omega}{\omega^{2}+\gamma^{2}}$$

The code in *Mathematica*:

```
Integrate[Sin[s*ω]*(1/(Exp[β*ℏ*ω] -1))*ω/(ω^2 + γ^2), {ω, -Infinity, Infinity},
  Assumptions -> {ℏ > 0, s >= 0, γ > 0, β > 0}]
```

The result is:

$$\frac{-\pi}{2}\cdot e^{-s\cdot \gamma}$$

If I suppose that $\beta$ is small and expand the exponential in the integrand, and keep the lowest term the result would be zero. However, the result for the unexpanded term does not depend on $\beta$. Why does expanding the exponential lead to an incorrect answer?

Comment: If you expand the exponential in $\beta$, doesn't that whole term become $\frac{1}{\beta \hbar \omega}$?  I don't obviously see why the integral of $\frac{\sin(s\omega)}{\omega^{2} + \gamma^{2}}$ is zero.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer the integrand is odd.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer. Yes it does. After that the integral is odd and the limit of integration is over a symmetric rage of negative and positive values so the result would be zero.

Comment: why would you expect to get the correct result from your approximation procedure? It seems to me that you cannot use the dominated convergence theorem, for example.

Comment: Oh, duh.  Yes.  Shouldn't math in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

The integrand is not analytic at $\beta = 0$ so expanding around $\beta = 0$ does not make sense.

Comment: What if we expand around a variable which is small but not zero?

Comment: The integrand has a simple pole at $\beta=0$, so expanding *could* make sense. I think the problem here is global, not local.